# How to make a drive NTFS from EXT4?

Tags: ntfs, ext4

I want to know how to make a drive ( non-system ) from EXT4 to NTFS. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't believe that you can convert a drive from one format to another. You can back up all of the data; reformat the drve to NTFS; and restore the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is enough space on disk,you can first shrink it using any software like [gparted](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gparted) and then format it to NTFS.However the best option is Backup-Format-Restore.

Comment: Shrinking it without creating a second NTFS partition would still lead to data loss.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you would need to back up the data to some other location, reformat your drive as NTFS, then restore the data.  There is no way to change from one filesystem type to another without wiping out what's on it at the time.