# Formatting hard drive from ext4 to ntfs

Tags: windows

I currently have ubuntu 12.04 installed on my computer, but i wan't to change back to Windows 7, but when i tried to install Windows 7 via a DVD/CD, it couldn't install on any of my hard drives. This is mainly because my hard drive's file system is "ext4" and not "ntfs." Also i have tried to format the drive, but it shows up with an error stating that my hard drive is "busy."

Comment: possibly answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/177438/how-to-make-a-drive-ntfs-from-ext4

Comment: you need to use gparted as indicated in the answer above, burn it on cd and boot it up, that way you make sure that the hard disk is not mounted

Comment: I am unable to do anything in Gparted, all the options i have available on my partition "Unmount," "Manage Flags" and "Information"

Comment: please upload gparted screenshot by seeing http://askubuntu.com/questions/417295/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-then-upload-the-image-to-imgur-through-terminal

Answer (score 3):

Use GParted as indicated in the comments above. You have to use it outside of the Ubuntu installation, as you can't format Ubuntu's partitions while it is using them. You can use a live environment disk, like the installation disk you used - if you don't have it you can download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You can also use a Gparted Live disk, available from [here](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Boot from one of those disks. and open GParted.

You need to <kbd>Unmount</kbd> before you can do anything. Then right-click, <kbd>Format to →</kbd>, <kbd>ntfs</kbd>.
 Then Press the  tick to apply the changes: [image: image of tick]

Remember to backup any data beforehand.

Comment: As i Unmount the disk this happens "The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:

/

Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually."

Comment: You cannot do it from inside Ubuntu - you have to use a live environment disk, like the installation disk you used - if you don't have it you can download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You can also use a Gparted Live disk, available from [here](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Comment: It didn't work either.