# Format external hard drive with ubuntu installed on it (for use as a Windows external)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I installed a new Windows hard-drive in my computer and took the old one (Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it) out and put this in an external hard drive encasing.

The problem I am facing now is that Windows does not pick this external hard drive up (the only way to use the hard drive is to switch the laptop off, plug the external in and boot into the Ubuntu OS installed on the external. How do I format this hard drive for use as a Windows external?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Formatting hard drive from ext4 to ntfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418551/formatting-hard-drive-from-ext4-to-ntfs)

Firstly ubuntu formats its file system in ext4. Windows currently cannot natively read this type of file system.

There is a driver available such as http://www.ext2fsd.com/ that will allow windows to read/write to that type of FS.

If you just want to clear the drive completely and re-format back to ntfs try using gparted tool.